# Windows 7 Copy & Paste breaks

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Win 7 x64 Pro. If I leave my computer up for more than a few hours my copy and paste no longer works, on anything. I can not copy files and paste them elsewhere, txt, anything.

If I reboot, its back to normal, for a few hours. Any ideas?

Comment: What applications do you have running? Can you post a hijackthis log?

Answer (score -1):

Use [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) tool

Comment: Files aren't the only things copied/cut/pasted.  The OP's also mentioned that the entire clipboard's broken.

Comment: Agreed! if you can please take back the -1, I  will delete this post.